# Prove that multiplication by random matrices recovers eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, covariance, random-matrices

First, let $\mathbf{A}$ be an $N\times N$ semidefinite (covariance) matrix and $\mathbf{X}$ be an $N\times M$ random matrix whose columns $\mathbf{x}_i$ are i.i.d. jointly Gaussian random vectors. We can compute the eigenvector / singular value decomposition

\begin{align}
\mathbf{T\Lambda T}^\top = \mathbf{X}^\top\mathbf{A}\mathbf{X}
\end{align}

and can subsequently define an $N\times M$ matrix
\begin{align}
\mathbf{P}=\mathbf{X}\mathbf{T}.
\end{align}

I would like to show that the (column normalized) column vectors in $\mathbf{P}$ are the eigenvectors of $\mathbf{A}$ in the case where $\left<\mathbf{x}_i\mathbf{x}_j^\top\right>=\delta_{ij}$, where angle brackets denote expectation, and in the limit of large $M,N$.

Proposed solution: For large $M, N$, $\mathbf{X}\mathbf{X}^\top\rightarrow M\mathbf{I}$ and $\mathbf{X}^{\top}\mathbf{X}\rightarrow N\mathbf{I}$.

If I left- and right-multiply my first equation by $\mathbf{X}$ and $\mathbf{X}^\top$, respectively, and substitute, I obtain

\begin{align}
\mathbf{X}\mathbf{T\Lambda T}^\top\mathbf{X}^\top &= \mathbf{X}\mathbf{X}^\top\mathbf{A}\mathbf{X}\mathbf{X}^\top\\
\implies \mathbf{P}\mathbf{\Lambda}\mathbf{P}^\top &= M^2\mathbf{A}. \tag{1}\label{1}
\end{align}

Furthermore, I have that
\begin{align}
\mathbf{P}^\top\mathbf{P}&= \mathbf{T}^\top\mathbf{X}^\top\mathbf{X}\mathbf{T}\\
&=N\mathbf{I}
\end{align}

so that the normalized matrix $\tilde{\mathbf{P}}=N^{-1/2}\mathbf{P}$ is orthonormal, where we have also used the orthonormality of $\mathbf{T}$. Substituting this into \eqref{1} and rearranging yields

\begin{align}
\frac{N}{M^2}\tilde{\mathbf{P}}\mathbf{\Lambda}\tilde{\mathbf{P}}^\top &= \mathbf{A}.
\end{align}

By uniqueness of the eigenvector decomposition, we can then conclude that $\tilde{\mathbf{P}}$ are the eigenvectors of $\mathbf{A}$. This seems fairly sensible except that $\mathbf{P}$ is not square...

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment.

- What is the meaning of $\propto$ ?
- If $\mathbf{X}$ is an $N\times M$ matrix of Gaussian variables should $\mathbf{T\Lambda T}^\top$ not be random ?

I guess you mean that the elements of $\mathbf{X}$ are numbers that were drawn
independently from a standard Gaussian distribution.

If $Y$ is an $\mathbb R^N$-valued Gaussian random vector with covariance matrix $\mathbb E[YY^\top]=\mathbf I$ and $\mathbf A$ is another covariance matrix with eigen decomposition
$$
\mathbf{Q\Gamma Q}^\top=\mathbf A
$$
then it is fairly easy to see that the transformed random vector
$$
Z=\mathbf Q\sqrt{\mathbf\Gamma} Y
$$
has covariance matrix
$$
\mathbb E[ZZ^\top]=\mathbb E[\mathbf Q\sqrt{\mathbf\Gamma}\,\,YY^\top\sqrt{\mathbf\Gamma}\mathbf Q^\top]=\mathbf Q\sqrt{\mathbf\Gamma}\,\,\underbrace{\mathbb E[YY^\top]}_{\mathbf I}\sqrt{\mathbf\Gamma}\mathbf Q^\top=\mathbf A\,.
$$
When your $M$ is large your many columns of $\mathbf X$ are many realizations of the random vector $Y\,.$ By the law of large numbers, averages taken over the columns
of $\mathbf X$ should be close to expectations. For example the
covariance matrix $\mathbf I$ should be
$$
\mathbb E[YY^\top]\approx\frac{1}{M}\mathbf{XX}^\top\,.
$$
Likewise, the covariance matrix $\mathbf A$ should be
$$
\mathbb E[ZZ^\top]\approx\frac{1}{M}\mathbf{Q\sqrt{\Gamma}XX}^\top\mathbf{\sqrt{\Gamma}Q}^\top\,.
$$

Comment: Thank you for your questions. I have made changes to try to clarify. Yes, $\mathbf{T \Lambda T}^\top$ should be random.

Comment: Should $\mathbf{T \Lambda T}^\top$ not be an $M\times M$ matrix ? Likewise, $\mathbf{T}$ and $\mathbf{\Lambda}$ ? The $\mathbf{P}=\mathbf{XT}$ should be an $N\times \color{red}{M}$ matrix. I am having trouble to relate $\mathbf{P}$ to the $N\times N$ matrix $\mathbf{Q\Xi}$ because I believe that $M$ must be large for the law of large numbers to hold.

Comment: Thanks. I once again made some edits, this time more major. You are correct that $\mathbf{T\Lambda T}^\top$ is $M\times M$. I have backed off of taking expectations of matrix products and am now just considering the case where $M$ and $N$ are large.

Comment: Still confusing. We now seem to agree on the dimensions of the matrices. $\mathbf{A}$ is $N\times N$ and $\mathbf{P}$ is $N\times M$. You want to show that the columns of $\mathbf{P}$ are the eigenvectors of $\mathbf{A}$. But we know that there are only $N$ such eigenvectors and $\mathbf{P}$ has $M$ columns.